# Can SQL Server perform hash-based row equality by itself (for MERGE operations)?

Tags: sql-server

A system I'm developing uses SQL Server to store query results in tables. Groups of rows represent a snapshot of data for a particular date (`DataDate`), which eventually expires as new data replaced it. The table retains old data instead of overwriting it. Here's a quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE query1234Results (
    -- Metadata columns:
    AccountId   int      NOT NULL,
    DataDate    date     NOT NULL,
    Appeared    datetime NOT NULL,
    Disappeared datetime     NULL,
    Updated     datetime NOT NULL,

    -- Query result columns:
    TotalSales                money,
    NewCustomers              int,
    CountHovercraftFullOfEels float,
    SumScratchedTobacconists  decimal
    -- etc...

    PRIMARY KEY ( AccountId, DataDate, Appeared )
)
```

- `AccountId` is because this is a multi-tenant system.
- `Appeared` is the date-time that result appeared.
- `Disappeared` is the date-time that the result stopped appearing in data results.
- `DataDate` is the date that the row corresponds to.
- `Updated` is the date-time the record's current state was last affirmed.

When data for this table is received by the application, it inserts it to the table using a `MERGE` query like this;

```
MERGE query1234Results AS t
USING @tableValuedParamter AS s ON
    t.AccountId = s.AccountId AND
    t.DataDate  = s.DataDate  AND
    t.Disappeard IS NULL AND

    t.TotalSales   = s.TotalSales AND
    t.NewCustomers = s.NewCustomers AND
    t.CountHovercraftFullOfEels = s.CountHovercraftFullOfEels AND
    t.SumScratchedTobacconists = s.SumScratchedTobacconists,
    -- etc

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    t.Updated = GETUTCDATE()

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        AccountId,
        Appeared,
        Disappeared,
        Updated,

        TotalSales,
        NewCustomers,
        CountHovercraftFullOfEels,
        SumScratchedTobacconists,
        -- etc
    )
    VALUES (
        s.AccountId,
        s.Appeared,
        NULL,
        GETUTCDATE(),

        s.TotalSales,
        s.NewCustomers,
        s.CountHovercraftFullOfEels, 
        s.SumScratchedTobacconists,
        -- etc
    )

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND
    t.AccountId = s.AccountId AND
    t.Disappeared IS NULL

    THEN UPDATE SET
        t.Disappeared = GETUTCDATE(),
        t.Updated     = GETUTCDATE()
```

This design works well for small data sets, but when the `MERGE` query needs to `INSERT` over 100,000 records (i.e. data for 100,000 days for a single `AccountId`) and when the table has 30+ query result columns it encounters performance issues as you'd expect.

Part of the problem is that SQL Server needs to perform equality checks for every non-metadata column in order for it to determine if it should `INSERT` data or `UPDATE` it.

Obviously this can be improved by adding the right indexes, but I get the feeling that I'd need to add an index that included every non-metadata column in order for the `MERGE` comparison to run quickly. I don't think this approach would scale well.

There is a workaround that exists, using a hash-of-values strategy to compute a hash for all the non-metadata values and using only that for the `MERGE` join condition, like so:

1. Add another metadata column, `Hash bigint` which stores the 64-bit MurmurHashV2 computed from the non-metadata columns of the data about to be `MERGE`.
2. Change the `MERGE` to this:

   ```
   MERGE query1234Results AS t
   USING @tableValuedParamter AS s ON
       t.AccountId = s.AccountId AND
       t.DataDate  = s.DataDate  AND
       t.Disappeard IS NULL      AND
       t.Hash      = s.Hash

   WHEN MATCHED...
   ```

There's a problem of the risk of hash-collisions so the `MERGE` query must still do a comparison of all the values fields - but SQL doesn't provide for short-circuiting `AND`/`OR` operators, so I don't know how to instruct SQL Server to only do the expensive value comparison only if the hash comparison succeeded.

This had me thinking that actually including the hash of the values in the row itself is a violation of separation-of-concerns: the hash value should be stored in an index somewhere maintained by the DBMS and only the DBMS should concern itself with that, not my application logic.

...but I know that if I do create an index on all the non-metadata-columns that it *will* create a conventional B-Tree based index that will necessarily be huge because it will store every unique value from the source table.

My question: Is there a way for SQL Server to create a hash-based index to optimize multiple-column equality checks without needing to incorporate this hash logic in my application domain? And if not, is my proposed approach of storing the hash in the table the best substitute?

Comment: careful using a hash function; read up on birthday paradox. And don't use CHECKSUM() use a wide HASHBYTES(). The problem with CHECKSUM is that it returns an int and you have a reasonable chance of getting a collision. You can of course create a covering NC index across all your columns.

Comment: @MitchWheat Right - I'd have to combine the hash equality check with a non-metadata column equality check, but I'd have to trust SQL Server to short-circuit the `ON` clause and check the hash first - but how can I get that guarantee?

Comment: It looks like another XY problem. Why do you want such structure and behavior at all? It seems that you are implementing journaling or monitoring subsystem. If so, you need extremely lightweight insert operations. Why searching for _similar old records_?

Comment: This is an interesting question that I did not encounter before in any form.

Comment: The execution plan may be sub-optimal due to underestimated row count estimates for the TVP. Try using a temp table instead to improve the estimates (e.g. `SELECT * INTO #tableValuedParameter FROM @tableValuedParamter` and use that as the `MERGE` source.

Answer (score 1):

> Part of the problem is that SQL Server needs to perform equality checks for every non-metadata column in order for it to determine if it should INSERT data or UPDATE it.

Before I answer the rest I'd like to make sure that this is indeed the problem. How have you determined that the number of equality comparisons is the issue? I personally would be hard pressed to determine that. You can test it by deleting most of the comparisons and using test data where you know that the conditions were not needed.

I suspect this will not be the issue.

Although I cannot tell you if SQL Server is going to short circuit these `AND` conditions (`but SQL doesn't provide for short-circuiting AND/OR operators`) I suspect it does. The specification of `AND` does not talk about evaluation but it does not have it. It only talks about the semantics. The semantics do not allow you to distinguish whether there was short circuiting or not. Therefore, SQL Server can perform this optimization. It seems like a common case to optimize.

Of course short circuiting might not help much if the data is such that most conditions must be evaluated anyway. But again, I suspect this point is moot.

> Obviously this can be improved by adding the right indexes

It is enough to add one index that is specific enough so that most comparisons are handled by the index. The purpose of the index is to avoid quadratic checking costs (every source row against every destination row). Adding all other columns will not help performance. Whether SQL Server equality compares during the index operation or in a succeeding filter step does not matter much. Maybe the filter is even a bit faster(?).

> There is a workaround that exists, using a hash-of-values strategy to compute a hash for all the non-metadata values and using only that for the MERGE join condition, like so:

If you find that these comparisons really hurt performance then this strategy can make sense. If you expect hashes to not match most of the time then make that comparison first. Likely, all other comparisons fall away due to short circuiting. If the hash matches most of the time then it will not help because the other comparisons must be evaluated anyway. You could use a cryptographic hash so that you don't have to check each column. Crypto hashes are entirely reliable for practical concerns.

> This had me thinking that actually including the hash of the values in the row itself is a violation of separation-of-concerns

If it works for you it's OK. That's really the only criterion that matters. Don't decide based on such blanket rules. Take every concern into account, weigh them and decide looking at the whole solution.

> Is there a way for SQL Server to create a hash-based index

Hekaton has a hash based index. This would work. But it also means that each query must hash the source data to match on. You cannot precompute it.